# extratinf RGB components frm HEX digit in java

Tags: java, colors, hex

i have color= #12FFFF  . that is color in this format where 12FFFF are hexadecima numbers.Now i want to get the each of indepenent R,G,B componetents in decimal.
How do i do it in java?

Answer (score 2):

It's not clear what your question is, but assuming color is a string, then I think you can do this:

```
String color = "#12FFFF";
int rgb = Integer.decode(color);
Color c = new Color(rgb);
int red = c.getRed();
int green = c.getGreen();
int blue = c.getBlue();
```

Here's the doc for [Color](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/awt/Color.html)

Answer (score 0):

Use bit operations - shifts and masks:

```
int rgb = 0x123456;

int red = (rgb >>> 16) & 0xff;
int green = (rgb >>> 8) & 0xff;
int blue = (rgb >>> 0) & 0xff;
```

(Obviously the right-shift-by-0 is irrelevant, but it's nicely consistent.)

If you don't already have your RGB value as an integer, please give more details in your question.

Answer (score 0):

```
int rgb = 0x123456;

Color c = new Color(rgb);
int red = c.getRed();
int blue = c.getBlue();
int green = c.getGreen();
```

If the hex is in a String you'll need to create a Long first and take the intValue() to construct the color.